# How to add post data from custom form to custom table in Magento 2?

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-2.3, magento2.2

I have gone through a number of links but didn't find any relevant answers.
I am doing that using Model/ResourceModel and on printing I am getting post data from the Custom form but it is not getting inserted in the custom table.

Please share the code or reference link.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Create an xml file : routename_controllername_actionname.xml to call phtml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="CustomB2BRFQ\Module\Block\RequestForQuoteForm" name="custom_module_form"
                   template="CustomB2BRFQ_Module::rfq.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Step 2 : Create your phtml file: Like in my case

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <form name="addData" method="post" id="addData" class="form" action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>"
         data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
            <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <legend class="legend"><span>Request For Quote</span></legend>
                <fieldset class="fieldset row">
                    <div class="fields col-md-6">
                        <div class="field name required">
                            <label class="label" for="uname"><span>Name</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                            <input name="uname" id="uname" title="Name" value="" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="email"><span>Email</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input name="email" id="email" title="Email" value="" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}">
                            </div>
                        </div>                       
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="category"><span>Category</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input name="category" id="category" title="Category" value="" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="company"><span>Company</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input type="text" name="company" id="company"  data-validate="{required:true}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="gstnumber"><span>GST Number</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input type="text" name="gstnumber" id="gstnumber"  data-validate="{required:true}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="phonenumber"><span>Phone Number</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input type="text" name="phonenumber" id="phonenumber"  data-validate="{required:true}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="itemsrequired"><span>Items Required</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input type="text" name="itemsrequired" id="itemsrequired"  data-validate="{required:true}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="location"><span>Location</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input type="text" name="location" id="location"  data-validate="{required:true}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
            </fieldset>
            </fieldset>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button type="submit" class="action submit primary" title="Save"><span>Submit Request</span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Step 3: Add logic to the controller file to save data to the database:

```
<?php
namespace CustomB2BRFQ\Module\Controller\Index;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /** @var  \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page */
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    
    /**
     * @var \CustomB2BRFQ\Module\Model\quoteFactory
     */
    protected $requestForQuoteFactory;


    /**
     * @var \CustomB2BRFQ\Module\Model\quote
     */
    protected $requestForQuote;
    
    
    /**      * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context      */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, 
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    \CustomB2BRFQ\Module\Model\RequestForQuoteFactory $requestForQuoteFactory,
    \CustomB2BRFQ\Module\Model\RequestForQuote $requestForQuote)
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->requestForQuoteFactory = $requestForQuoteFactory;
        $this->requestForQuote = $requestForQuote;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
     * Blog Index, shows a list of recent blog posts.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
     public function execute()
    {
         //return $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();die;
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        try{

            $request = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
            if(isset($request) && isset($request['uname']) && isset($request['email']) && isset($request['company'])
            && isset($request['category']) && isset($request['gstnumber']) && isset($request['itemsrequired']) && isset($request['location'])
            && isset($request['phonenumber'])){
            $uname = $request['uname'];
            $email = $request['email'];
            $company = $request['company'];
            $category = $request['category'];
            $gstnumber = $request['gstnumber'];
            $itemsrequired = $request['itemsrequired'];
            $location = $request['location'];
            $phonenumber = $request['phonenumber'];
            
            $requestquote = $this->requestForQuoteFactory->create();
            $requestquote->setName($uname);
            $requestquote->setEmail($email);
            $requestquote->setCompany($company);
            $requestquote->setCategory($category);
            $requestquote->setGstNumber($gstnumber);
            $requestquote->setItemsRequired($itemsrequired);
            $requestquote->setLocation($location);
            $requestquote->setPhoneNumber($phonenumber);

            $requestquote->save();
            $message = __('Quote is successfully submitted.');
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);
            $this->resultPageFactory->create();
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('quote/index/index');
        
        }else{
        $message = __('Filled all the details.');
        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);
        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
          
        }catch (\Exception $e){
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t submit your request, Please try again.'));
            $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('quote/index/index');
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!
I tried and it's working